# SNMP Walk and Get / GetNext for MIBs that are not supported by agent

Tags: snmp

Our agent currently does not supports all OIDs and Group in 1.3.6.1.2.1.10.7 .

Say the agents only support 1.3.6.1.2.1.10.7.11 group. Now if give SNMP Walk / GetNext / Get on 1.3.6.1.2.1.10.7.5.1.2 (leaf) or say 1.3.6.1.2.1.10.7.5 (table) should the agent return 1.3.6.1.2.1.10.7.11.1 or something else.

Comment: Removed implementation tags; this is about the spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### GetNext

*GetNext* will give you the current value of the next object, found numerically *after* the requested OID, which exists and is supported.

<sub>(Or, if no such object exists, the response is sent back with the field set to the special *noSuchName* error value.)</sub>

<sub>(Or, if the response would be too big, the response is sent back with the field set to the special *tooBig* error value.)</sub>

<sub>(Or, if there was some other problem, the response is sent back with the field set to the special *genErr* error value.)</sub>

A walk is built on *GetNext* requests (or *GetBulk*, which is the same but with more efficient transport).

You can [read all about it in the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1157#page-21).

---

> Now if give SNMP Walk / GetNext <strike>/ Get</strike> on 1.3.6.1.2.1.**10.7.5.1.2** (leaf) or say 1.3.6.1.2.1.**10.7.5** (table) should the agent return 1.3.6.1.2.1.**10.7.1**

No. That would be going backwards in the MIB. It's *GetNext*, not *GetPrevious*.

> or something else.

Yes, probably something under 1.3.6.1.2.1.**11**, though this depends on the capabilities and configuration of your agent — it's possible that it does not support any objects in *that* subtree, either!

> should the agent return 1.3.6.1.2.1.**10.7.11.1**

Yes, that would be a compliant, and reasonable, thing for it to do.

---

#### Get

> if give SNMP <strike>Walk / GetNext /</strike> Get on 1.3.6.1.2.1.**10.7.5.1.2** (leaf) or say 1.3.6.1.2.1.**10.7.5** (table) should the agent return 1.3.6.1.2.1.**10.7.11.1** or something else.

[It'll just return *noSuchName*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1157#page-20).

There is no navigation mechanism in *Get*.

Indeed, this is why *GetNext* was added!

Comment: Thanks - so I understand that returning 1.3.6.1.2.1.10.7.1 on a GetNext request on OID not supported is expected then - please confirm and what on Get command then?

Comment: _"and what on Get command then?"_ I didn't understand, sorry.

Comment: Sorry updated the question - Now if give SNMP Walk / GetNext / Get on 1.3.6.1.2.1.10.7.5.1.2 (leaf) or say 1.3.6.1.2.1.10.7.5 (table) should the agent return 1.3.6.1.2.1.10.7.11.1 or something else.

Comment: User can select a leaf say 1.3.6.1.2.1.10.7.10.1.2 and issue a Get command also - what should be the expected behaviour?

Comment: Added to the answer. I do wonder why you didn't just test it though?

Comment: I am supporting a agent product and new to SNMP - thanks for all the information but now I understand that GetNext / Walk on a OID not supportted either from a leaf / aggregate level should return the OID that is next supported - be it outside the table / group - sorry please let  me more on GET command behaviour?

Comment: What more do you want to know? Seriously, you are going to need to do some reading up/research. I'm not going to teach you all the fundamentals of SNMP one at a time here... When I started on SNMP a few years ago to create an SNMP agent, it only took a few days to grasp the basics by reading the specs & various materials online. Feel free to come back after doing that if you have specific questions.